# Folders in Pages Library?

Tags: 2007, publishing-site

In a publishsing site, there is a library called Pages. The web interface does not allow to create directories underneath.

However, it's possible to create directories via SharePoint designer.

This pages seem accessible.

- What are the risks and side effects of these folders?
- Why is not possible in the web interface?

Answer (score 3):

Note that SharePoint 2007 (MOSS) does not support folders in the Pages directory when publishing pages are used, whereas this is supported in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Additionally, these folders could potentially cause significant issues in the upgrade to 2010 - or it may do nothing. Either way, folders in /Pages/ in SP2007 is unsupported and Microsoft will not provide *any* support for your farm should you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the folder content type applied to your pages library or is it configured to not allow folders?  I've created folders in libraries on publishing sites for instances where a few pages needed to be secured from the regular users.  I creaed it as a subfolder in the pages library instead of creating a separate secured library.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly a matter of changing a setting as follows:

*Document Library Settings> Advanced Settings> Folders> Display "New Folder" command on the New menu?> YES*

This defaults to NO for Pages libraries in publishing sites in 2007.